# Cannot access 192.168.1.1

Tags: 14.04, internet

I cannot access 192.168.1.1 in Ubuntu 14.04.I use wireless router TP-LINK TD-W8901G.It worked on windows but it doesn't work on Ubuntu.Any ideas what should I do?

The output of ifconfig is:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 60:a4:4c:4e:94:ab  
      inet6 addr: fe80::62a4:4cff:fe4e:94ab/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:47087 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:49475 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:35977992 (35.9 MB)  TX bytes:7791380 (7.7 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:9663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:9663 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
      RX bytes:1065746 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1065746 (1.0 MB)

ppp0      Link encap:Point-to-Point Protocol  
      inet addr:122.168.19.182  P-t-P:122.168.4.1  Mask:255.255.255.255
      UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1492  Metric:1
      RX packets:3493 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:4238 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:3 
      RX bytes:911258 (911.2 KB)  TX bytes:742138 (742.1 KB)
```

The output of ping 192.168.1.1 is :

```
PING 192.168.1.1 (192.168.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 125.21.0.109 icmp_seq=1 Destination Net Unreachable
From 125.21.0.109 icmp_seq=2 Destination Net Unreachable
From 125.21.0.109 icmp_seq=3 Destination Net Unreachable
From 125.21.0.109 icmp_seq=4 Destination Net Unreachable
```

Then it went to infinite loop.I had to interrupt it.

Comment: I assume 192.168.1.1 is your router IP address. Do you have an IP address set on wireless interface of your Ubuntu machine? Also the wireless interface is setup correctly?

Comment: What exactly is 192.168.1.1? I am assuming it is the TP-Link device. Please [edit] your question and add the output of `ifconfig` and `ping 192.168.1.1`. You should also explain how you are attemting to connect to the router. Also, what do you mean you have it "on Desktop"?

Comment: I think you connected your main Internet cable directy into your PC as I see your ppp0 interface has an IP address. Try to move the cable into the WAN port of the router and then another cable back from a LAN port on the router to the PC or use wireless if it is setup on the router.

Comment: Telephone cable is connected to router and LAN cable is connected to router and to PC.

Comment: According to the following article, the link for TP-Link modems is 192.168.0.1 https://techempty.org/how-to/192-168-1-1-not-working/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ifconfig` output shows that your *eth0* device does not have an associated IP address.

- Does your computer tell you you are indeed connected to the AP?

You can set a static IP address in the 192.168.1.0/24 range (ie: 192.168.1.201) with a gateway of 192.168.1.1 and attempt accessing your router after that.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone,I used this command:

```
sudo dhclient eth0
```

And now I have access.